# Does quantum theory obey locality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, locality

Bell's inequality together with the Aspect experiment shows that that we cannot have [local realism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality#Local_realism). But does quantum theory obey [locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality)? and if not how can locality be violated but not special relativity? Can you (if possible) also provide a source with your answer

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186479/

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170416/

Comment: i think the distinction between quantum non-locality (entanglement) and Einsteinian non-locality (super-luminal propagation of information) in the question above answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The choice of measurement basis on one half of an entangled state affects the other half. Can this be used to communicate faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/the-choice-of-measurement-basis-on-one-half-of-an-entangled-state-affects-the-ot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

The term "quantum non-locality" refers to the fact that quantum mechanics cannot be described by a local classical hidden variable model. This is the content of [Bell's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

In particular, locality is not violated. The statement of the theorem is that if we assume (wrongly) that quantum mechanics is described by a classical hidden variable model, **then** locality is violated. This doesn't tell us that quantum mechanics violate locality, this tells us that quantum mechanics cannot be described by a local classical model.

**An opinionated remark regarding terminology**

"Non-locality" is really misleading (although common) terminology. A less confusing term for this might be simply "bell-inequality-violation". A term that describes a broader class of these no-go theorems is "non-classicality", which is also much less misleading.